# RemoteSystem.FindByHostNameAsync doesn't work with windows 11 machine

Tags: c#, uwp, network-programming, windows-11

I want to discover remote system in UWP application by its IP address:

```
Windows.Networking.HostName deviceHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName("192.168.1.105");

var status = await RemoteSystem.RequestAccessAsync();

var remoteSys = await RemoteSystem.FindByHostNameAsync(deviceHost);
```

The code is exactly the same as in MSDN samples. IP address is valid, ping works, `status` is fine.
But the code doesn't work properly returning `remoteSys` is null.
I have RemoteSystem and Private networks capabilities in package manifest.

Remote system is Windows 11 so it may be related to some specific issue (firewall, network settings, etc.). Could you please advise how I can solve it?

Update: if I try to discover remote system from Windows 11 and the remote system is Windows 10 - the same code works fine!

Comment: Have you checked `Remote Desktop` toggle button is on in **Settings>System>Remote Desktop**? Can this problem be reproduced in the official sample? https://github.com/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/RemoteSystems

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I am sure this problem is the same for official sample and I found the setting which solves it, see my posted answer. It would be great to have this problem mentioned in official documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not related to the code. This depends on settings of Windows machine which we try to find as `RemoteDevice`. So it is necessary to change the following Windows settings:

**Settings->Network & Internet**

There it can the following option: select your network, network settings, Network profile type. It is Public by default for Win11 and need to change it to Private (this should be done only for local networks) and then this machine can be founded with `RemoteDevice` API.

Or it may look like this: **Settings->Network & Internet->Advanced network settings->Advanced sharing settings->Network discovery** - set it to ON if you want this machine to be foundable.

For different versions of Windows 11 and Windows 10 it may look different but their meaning is the same, you need to switch on Network Discovery. For Windows 11 it is off mostly, for Windows 10 it is sometimes off (don't know if this depends on update/version).

I wish it would be mentioned somewhere in `RemoteDevice` documentation.